# Visual Studio Online - Deploy HTML/JS only application directly, without compile

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-deployment

If you have a pure HTML/JS project, that does not require any kind of compilation or anything - but the deploy is basically just to copy the files to a web app - how do you do that?

I already have 20+ .Net projects set up for Continuous integration and Deployment, and it works great - but I cannot figure out how to do this (seemingly simpler) thing.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note**: Not Sure, if release without build is a good practise.But your scenario looks ok.

In Release pipeline, you can use/add an copy task like [[Windows machine file copy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/deploy/windows-machine-file-copy) / [Copy Files Over SSH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/deploy/copy-files-over-ssh) / [FTP upload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/utility/ftp-upload) / [Publish Build Artifacts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/utility/publish-build-artifacts) /..] to your destination machine/File share. Release would proceed as usual with this automatically

You can add/append any of these task directly in any of your existing feasible Release definitions if solution/Code path is accessible else create a new Release definition with any of feasible specified task

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to make sure your build agent could access your target machine. If Host agents can't access the target machine where holds the web app, [deploy a private agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/actions/agents/v2-windows) is necessary.

Then, in your build/release definition, you could add [Windows Machine File Copy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/deploy/windows-machine-file-copy) task to copy the files.